# how can I write a regex of only transmit one site traffic?

Tags: regex

This is a regex of my proxy auditing rules.

```
(.*\.|)(abc|juniper|cisco|nilos)\.(org|com|net)
```

add this auditing rule my proxy will not transmit the upper websites traffic.

I mean wether I can only transmit one website's traffic?

such as `juniper.net`, how can I write the regex?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking.

Comment: I mean this regex, it forbid those site to transmit traffic, whether I can change the regex, let it only  transmit those site's traffic?

Comment: That sounds like it would depend greatly on your proxy software, which you haven't told us anything about.